# statsmodels: clarification on VAR(p) results attribute, results.forecast_interval()

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, statsmodels

I am trying to look for the upper and lower limits of my time series data, and follow the instructions from [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#class-reference) to use the VAR(p)

Below is my code

```
model = tsa.VAR(data)
results = model.fit(maxlags=13, ic='aic')
results.forecast_interval(results.y, steps=2)
```

Below is results from the third line of code above (I used 3 features hence the 3 columns)

```
(array([[ 0.38247778,  0.85441826,  0.09361418],
        [ 0.35598097,  0.93346637,  0.09222475]]),
 array([[ 0.25124841, -0.1505907 ,  0.0761289 ],
        [ 0.21548388, -0.0815039 ,  0.07375073]]),
 array([[ 0.51370715,  1.85942722,  0.11109945],
        [ 0.49647805,  1.94843664,  0.11069876]]))
```

There's not much explanation on what those numbers mean other than what the website says

```
VARResults.forecast_interval(y, steps, alpha=0.05)
Construct forecast interval estimates assuming the y are Gaussian
Returns:    (lower, mid, upper) : (ndarray, ndarray, ndarray)
```

Do the `lower`, `mid`, `upper` mean lower limit, mean and upper limit respectively?

If not, does anyone know if there's an attribute to find the upper and lower limit or the standard deviation?

Comment: If it doesn't make sense, then check the code in case the documentation is wrong, which is the case here, `return point_forecast, forc_lower, forc_upper`. The first array is forecast (mean), second is lower confint, third is upper confint http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.html#VARResults and search page for `forecast_interval`

Comment: Thank you for the link to the source code!! couldn't find it before...